# Read write using Stream.Readbyte and stream.Writebyte in C#

Tags: c#, stream

What is wrong with the following code?

```
        Stream inputstream = File.Open("e:\\read.txt", FileMode.Open);
        Stream writestream = File.Open("e:\\write.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

        do
        {
            writestream.WriteByte((byte)inputstream.ReadByte());
        }
        while (inputstream.ReadByte() != -1);
```

read.txt has "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."

Whereas the write.txt file contains few contents skimmed "teqikbonfxjme vrtelz o."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're only writing every other byte because you're consuming one in the `while` check.

Comment: Thank You. Oops I got to improve my common sense

Comment: Just get some practice with the Debugger and you'll be rockin' in no time.

Answer (score 5):

You are writing only odd bytes, because you are skipping even bytes when do another reading in `where` condition.

Modify your code this way:

```
int byteRead;
while((byteRead = inputstream.ReadByte()) != -1)
   writestream.WriteByte((byte)byteRead);
```

BTW you can use `File.Copy("e:\\read.txt", "e:\\write.txt")` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
while (inputstream.Position <= inputstream.Length)
{
    writestream.WriteByte((byte)inputstream.ReadByte());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `inputstream.ReadByte()` method makes you cursor to move by one.

You need to read the byte once, and if it not -1 then write it. Just like that:

```
int read = inputstream.ReadByte();
while (read != -1)
{ 
    writestream.WriteByte((byte)read ); 
    read = inputstream.ReadByte();
}
```